# Copy memory attribute for NSString accessed from different threads

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Is a NSString copied on every access to the property if its declared as `(nonatomic, copy)` ?

Is there a need to wrap access to the string with NSLock if the string is accessed/mutated from different threads and its declared with copy?

Answer (score 1):

The `copy` attribute indicates that, when assigning the property, a copy of the object will be made. The setter should look something like:

```
- (void)setMyProperty:(NSString *)value {
    _myProperty = [value copy];
}
```

However, the getter always returns the object's own copy:

```
- (NSString *)myProperty {
    return _myProperty;
}
```

Lastly, if the property is a `NSString *`, which is immutable, there is no problem if there are many threads reading it at the same time. There is no need to use a lock for accessing the property.

Take a look at Apple's documentation: [Copy Properties Maintain Their Own Copy](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW35).